# Redshift dollar quoting inside a procedure

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a procedure which accepts the table name and the 3 fields that need filling. This is to be called from another procedure that loops through another table deciding which sub-table to put stuff into. The important bit is a simple insert statement, e.g.

```
insert into table1 values
('blah','String','50');
```

So that 4 parameters coming in (table1, and the 3 values). How would I do this using dollar quoting? Obviously this doesnt work but gives you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
create or replace procedure 
  insert_dc_table(p_tblname varchar,
                  p_name varchar, 
                  p_datatype varchar, 
                  p_datalen varchar)
as $$
begin
  execute
      'insert into '||p_tblname||'(name,datatype,datalen) values '
    ||'('
    ||p_name||', '
    ||p_datatype||', '
    ||p_datalen
    ||')';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I'd need double-dollars around some, but am unsure of exactly where $$ and quotes go in all this !*&#!
I could declare a variable to hold the execute statement and do:

```
declare a _output varchar(200);
  a_output := $$ insert into $$||p_tblname||$$(name,datatype,datalen) values ( '$$||p_name||$$',
```

well, i get lost there!
Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

Redshift Stored Procedures only require dollar quoting of the procedure body. Quotes inside the the procedure body are interpreted as normal.

You may find that your SQL client does not submit the SP create correctly due to the dollar quotes. If so I recommend using `psql` to create the stored procedure.

[Sample stored procedures are available in our "Amazon Redshift Utils" GitHub repository.](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/StoredProcedures)

Here's a modification of your example:

```
-- DROP PROCEDURE insert_dc_table(VARCHAR,VARCHAR ,VARCHAR ,VARCHAR);
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_dc_table( 
    p_tblname VARCHAR, p_name VARCHAR, p_datatype VARCHAR, p_datalen VARCHAR )
AS $$
DECLARE
  rows  INTEGER;
BEGIN
    sql := 'INSERT INTO '||p_tblname||' (name, datatype, datalen)'
         ||' VALUES ('||p_name||','||p_datatype||','||p_datalen||');';
    RAISE INFO 'Running SQL: %', sql;
    EXECUTE sql;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS rows := ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE INFO 'Rows inserted = %', rows;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- CALL insert_dc_table ('test_table', 'name', 'type', 'length');
```